# How to copy InnerHtml to clipboard in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to copy the content of this for-loop into clipboard:

```
<div ref="text" class="links">
        <div class="row" v-for="(name, index) in resultNames" :key="index" >                                    
            <p>{{makeUrl(name)}} </p>
        </div>   
</div>  
<button   @click="handleCopy">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45041489/517235) answer and came up with this method:

```
  handleCopy() {
     this.$refs.text.select();
     document.execCommand('copy');
    }
```

But this results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs.text.select is not a function
```

So I'm left clueless how can I solve this withouth using third party javascript plugins?

**P.S.** I tried some JS specific suggested answers, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173194/select-all-div-text-with-single-mouse-click/1173319#1173319), but get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Comment: You can simply mirror the data in a hidden `<textarea>` and use that.

Comment: You need to take the `innerHTML` and put it inside a `textarea` and only then select and copy it.

Comment: @ChrisG how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)
More specifically - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/9839191)

Comment: @ChrisG That answer does not work in Vue.js. I tried and failed: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/484yxqpmm4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1173319/5734311) answer, here's a function to select an `HTMLElement`'s text:

```
selectText(element) {
  var range;
  if (document.selection) {
    // IE
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(element);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
}
```

What's left to do is to a) pass the element b) call the copy command:

```
this.selectText(this.$refs.text); // e.g. <div ref="text">
document.execCommand("copy");
```

Comment: it's not working - error message appeared: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."  when I put div's ref as parameter.

Comment: @Schroet make sure that your div contains only the text to copy in my case i used this to copy a phone number : <span ref="copyPhone">
                {{ phone_icon.phone }}
              </span>

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the vue plugin on npm:vue-clipboard

Lets first make the html data which you want to be copied. After that we can make use of the npm plugin to copy the html data

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        HTMLcontent:'',
        resultNames:["John","Steward","Rock"]
    },
    created() {
    },
    methods:{
        makeData(){
            var self = this;
            for(var i = 0; i < self.resultNames.length; i++){
                self.HTMLcontent += '<p>'+self.resultNames[i]+'</p>';
            }
        },
        copyData(){
            this.makeData();
            console.log(this.HTMLcontent);
        }
    }
});
```

After that install a vue-plugin

```
npm install --save v-clipboard
import Clipboard from 'v-clipboard'
Vue.use(Clipboard)
```

After that make change to the copyData function as below

```
copyData(){
    this.makeData();
    this.$clipboard(this.invite_code);
    alert("Copied to clipboard");
}
```

Hope that solves your query

Comment: For vue 2 use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-clipboard2

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but vue clipboard and clipboard2, didn't help me

In result for copy to clipbboard I used JQuery and vue events

HTML part

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control copyLinkInput" :value="link">
  <div class="input-group-append" @click="doCopy">
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue.js part

```
...

props: ['link'],
methods: {
  doCopy: function (e) {
    let selectEl = $(e.target).parents('.input-group').find('.copyLinkInput')[0];

    selectEl.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
}

...
```